# Pandas issue Converting % to float (by dividing by 100), I want it as string with % sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', dtype={'String Column': str})

print(df)
```

this is the code and here is the [XLSX](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yg0FheEs4xGmn6YOmiK51JmopH9Ii89qQOnBQVtvfHA/edit?usp=sharing).

what I want to do is I want to read `String Column` as str and other column as pandas read it.

here is the output I'm getting.

```
   Percentage Column String Column
0               0.05          0.02
1              45.00          0.05
2              39.00            44
```

The output I want:

```
   Percentage Column String Column
0               0.05            2
1              45.00            5
2              39.00            44
```

I've tried many things for this in code line:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', converters={'String Column': str})
df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', dtype={'String Column': object})
df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', dtype=str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `pandas.apply()` here?:

```
data=[['1',.02,.04],['2',.05,44]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
def _from_float(x):
  if x<1: return x*100
  else  : return x

df['col3'] = df['col3'].apply(_from_float).astype(int) ## or use str
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your excel file

your data types in pandas are ok

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', dtype={'String Column': str})

print(df.dtypes)
print()
print(df)
```

Results

```
Percentage Column    float64
String Column         object
dtype: object

   Percentage Column String Column
0               0.05          0.02
1              45.00          0.05
2              39.00            44
```

But your Excel files has configured the cells as percentage by default

[image]
[image]

> PD: Porcentaje = Percentage

You can set literal string in Excel `="2%"` save a run again.
I just put 2%, but you can put what you want, `int` etc.

```
Percentage Column    float64
String Column         object
dtype: object

   Percentage Column String Column
0               0.05            2%
1              45.00            5%
2              39.00            44
```

Comment: If my answer helps you, please do not forget to approve or vote, otherwise make a comment to improve the answer. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)